# how to set domainObjectName suffix in generateConfig.xml for mybatis generator

Tags: java, config, mybatis-generator

I encountered this situation:

table : t_user,t_manager,...

domainObjectName : UserEntity,ManagerEntity,...

I know how to replace the prefix using the domainObjectRenamingRule,

but how can i append the suffix?

Comment: ```xml
<domainObjectRenamingRule searchString="(?i)^t(.*)" replaceString="$1_Entity" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression capture group for this. For example:

```xml
<domainObjectRenamingRule searchString="^(?i)t(.*)" replaceString="$1Entity" />
```

Comment: @JeffBultler  
<domainObjectRenamingRule searchString="^t_(.*)" replaceString="$1Entity" /> doen't work in my case? can you share your full "table" element config?

Comment: It's probably a case sensitive thing. Try `searchString="^T_(.*)"`. Or you could make the regular expression case insensitive with `searchString="(?i)^t_(.*)"`.

Comment: @JeffBultler I have already tried the 2 solutions you offered.But failed.

Comment: Yeah - I looked at the code and realize what's wrong. The rename is taking place after the generator has calculated a name - the generator has stripped off the underscores so there shouldn't be an underscore in the search string. Try it one more time with `searchString="(?i)^t(.*)"`